# Turtlebot - Unable to acquire data image from camera

Tags: ros, 3d-visualization, groovy-turtlebot, turtlebot-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everybody,

I looked for a solution in the forum, analyzing the different answers/questions but I still don't find a solution to my problem.

Some basic information:

- Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit
- Groovy
- Turtlebot with Kobuki base

I followed the guide and there are no problems for communication, teleoperation and so on.
However, I am complitely not able to use the camera: basically, I don't acquire data information.

At this step, I have problem (reference: turtlebot_bringup/Tutorials/groovy/3D Visualisation )

In netbook:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch
```

Workstation:

```
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch
```

Everything seems ok but when I go in rviz, I have a warn in Image: No Image Received.

I tried different solutions but no ones worked. I am going to explain you.

First of all, kinect seems connected to my netbook. The light of kinect flashes green.
I tried all the possible USB port (to avoid USB 3.0 problems) but the result is the same.

```
turtlebot@turtlebot-W110ER:/opt/ros/groovy$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b34c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 014: ID 0403:6001 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT232 USB-Serial (UART) IC
Bus 003 Device 032: ID 045e:02c2 Microsoft Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 035: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Audio
Bus 003 Device 038: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. Xbox NUI Camera
```

So...This is the list of rosnode list from workstation

```
cvassall@hagurosan:groovy$ rosnode list
/app_manager
/bumper2pointcloud
/camera/camera_nodelet_manager
/camera/depth/metric
/camera/depth/metric_rect
/camera/depth/points
/camera/depth/rectify_depth
/camera/depth_registered/metric
/camera/depth_registered/metric_rect
/camera/depth_registered/rectify_depth
/camera/depthimage_to_laserscan_loader
/camera/disparity_depth
/camera/disparity_depth_registered
/camera/driver
/camera/ir/rectify_ir
/camera/openni_camera_loader
/camera/points_xyzrgb
/camera/points_xyzrgb_depth_rgb
/camera/register_depth_rgb
/camera/rgb/debayer
/camera/rgb/rectify_color
/camera/rgb/rectify_mono
/camera_nodelet_manager
/cmd_vel_mux
/diagnostic_aggregator
/master_sync_turtlebot_W110ER_7065_566021383
/mobile_base
/mobile_base_nodelet_manager
/robot_pose_ekf
/robot_state_publisher
/rosout
/rqt_gui_py_node_11279
/rviz
/zeroconf/zeroconf_avahi
```

Then I tried to get the image directly from kinect using the command

```
rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image
```

I obtain a white image.

Then, the last try. I killed 3dsensor.launch and I runned

```
cvassall@hagurosan:groovy$ rosrun openni_camera openni_node
```

but in turtlebot-pc and workstation, the answer is the same:

```
[ INFO] [1392211004.943802894]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
[ INFO] [1392211005.029530557]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
[ INFO] [1392211008.034147743]: No devices connected.... waiting for devices to be connected
```

What can I do to solve the problem?

I am beginner and maybe I skip some "basic" step about kinect but I followed everything in the Tutorial.
Thanks a lot

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/128571/turtlebot---unable-to-acquire-data-image-from-camera/) by [chri-vassallo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11886/chri-vassallo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-02-12

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `rostopic list` to see what topics you can subscribe to. You will see a lot of image related topics. Particularly, you can

> rosrun image_view image_view image:=/camera/rgb/image_color compressed

And that should work. Notice that the *compressed* is optional. `/camera/rgb/image_mono` is also working for me. I cannot see depth images using image_view yet (http://answers.ros.org/question/134686/turtlebot-depth-image-not-showing-in-image_view/) but they do show in RVIZ.

In RVIZ, expand the IMAGE line and try subscribing to some topic.

---

Originally posted by [aguadopd](https://answers.ros.org/users/6283/aguadopd/) with karma: 86 on 2014-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0